# I need to swap out two values in a string for one (C++)

Tags: c++, string, split, append

I am making a roman numeral converter. I have everything figured out except there is one problem at the end.

The string looks like `IVV`

I need to make it `IX`

I have split the string at each new letter, then appended them back on, then using an if statement to see if it contains 2 "V"s. I want to know if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: show us some code dude.

Comment: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and leverage it's [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) member functions.

Comment: You should post your code for searcing a solution

Comment: What part of the code do you need? all I have is a string that I need to replace certain characters in.

Comment: @Fusion You've beem requested to show what you have tried already! Just saying _'Gimme teh codez plz!'_ doesn't work well here :P ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) should help you tremendously as you can leverage its search and replace functionality. You'll want to start with the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function which allows you to search for a character or a string and returns an index where what you are searching for exists or [`npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) if the search fails.

You can then call [`replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) passing it the index returned by `find`, the number of characters you want to replace and what replace the range with.

The code below should help you get started.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string roman("IVV");

    // Search for the string you want to replace
    std::string::size_type loc = roman.find("VV");

    // If the substring is found replace it.
    if (loc != std::string::npos)
    {
        // replace 2 characters staring at position loc with the string "X"
        roman.replace(loc, 2, "X");
    }


    std::cout << roman << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same reason as I've been downvoting the other answer. [**Don't feed the help vampires!**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal/255020#255020)

Comment: You didn't serial downvote on my account in response to this?!? Did you?

Comment: Why would I? I totally disagree with you but I'm not a DB.

Comment: OK, already thought so. I just was curious ... (_'DB'_ BTW, I don't know this shortcut, would you mind enlightening me?)

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. No you're certainly not! I mostly like and agree with your answers and comments. (I'm watching "Two and a half men" currently, there's where you can see DB's in action ;) ...)

Answer (score -2):

You could use `std string` `find` and `rfind` operations, these find the position of the first and the last occurrence of the entered parameter, check if these are not equal and you will know

Answer updated

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string x1 = "IVV";
    if (x1.find('V') !=x1.rfind('V'))
    {
        x1.replace(x1.find('V'), 2, 'X');
    }
    return 0;
}
```